# Webscraping Issues Involving Clicking (Using R)

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape the following website:

http://www.healthgrades.com/hospital-directory/california-ca-san-mateo/affiliated-physicians-HGSTED418D46050070

I am using R to webscrape the website. Particularly, I am trying to copy all of doctor's names and specialties from this website. However, the main issue that I am dealing with is that the url link does not change when I press the arrow/next button. I can not use any basic techniques to webscrape this page. How can I solve this problem? It would be nice to have all of the data that I am collecting in one data matrix/spreadsheet.

Comment: Is it a `POST` form, or is it some Javascript/AJAX sorcery?

Comment: I am not particularly sure if it is a Post form or not. I am not familiar with this jargon. Check out the link to find out.

Answer (score 3):

```
dum <- "http://www.healthgrades.com/hospital-directory/california-ca-san-mateo/affiliated-physicians-HGSTED418D46050070"
library(XML)
ddum <- htmlParse(dum)
noofpages <- xpathSApply(ddum,'//*/span[@class="paginationItem active"]/following-sibling::*[1]',xmlValue)[1]
noofpages <- (as.numeric(gsub(' of ','',noofpages))-1)%/%5+1
doctors <- c(); dspec <- c()
for(i in 1:noofpages){
 if(i>1){
  ddum <- htmlParse(paste0(dum,"?pagenumber=",i,'#'))
 }
 doctors <- c(doctors, xpathSApply(ddum,'//*/a[@class="providerSearchResultSelectAction"]',xmlValue))
 dspec <- c(dspec, xpathSApply(ddum,'//*/div[@class="listingHeaderLeftColumn"]/p',xmlValue))
}

paste(doctors,dspec,sep=',')
#  [1] "Dr. Julia Adamian, MD,Internal Medicine"                               
#  [2] "Dr. Eric R. Adler, MD,Internal Medicine"                               
#  [3] "Dr. Ramzi S. Alami, MD,General Surgery"                                
#  [4] "Dr. Jason L. Anderson, MD,Internal Medicine"                           
#  [5] "Dr. Karl A. Anderson, MD,Urology"                                      
#  [6] "Dr. Christine E. Angeles, MD,Geriatric Medicine, Pulmonology"
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they're using the variable

```
?pagenumber=x
```

You can probably iterate over `x` to get your data.

---

On a side note,

I'm not sure which browser you are using, but Chrome has a handy feature where you can right click on a button and select `inspect element`.